# Chrome crashing from javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-2

I've been working on a page for the past week that uses google maps to display all of the counties in Georgia and allow the user to click on them and gather census data about the selected counties. The counties are in an array of GPolygons, and I've implemented the interactive map with this (sudo-code):

```
instantiate map;
fill polys[] array from vb code-behind;
for ( var i=0; i<polys.length; i++ ) {
    GEvent.addListener(polys[i], "click", function() {
        highlight polygon and select item in listbox;
        or
        un-highlight polygon and deselect item in listbox;
    }
}
```

This worked great while I was working on the page (testing the whole time in chrome), and as I was almost done working on it and the pages it interacts with the other day, it started crashing 90% of the time I opened it. These crashes are so intense that my computer takes close to 15 minutes to fully recover. It affects my whole computer, not just chrome. I commented out all of the javscript on the page and reintroduced it segment by segment, and the problem area is the for loop that creates the listeners on the polygon overlays. To verify that it is an issue with the loop itself and not the code within, I simulated the loop conditions and the web page still crashes in chrome. Even with a loop as simple as this:

```
var count=0;
for ( var i=0; i<5; i++)
    count=1;
alert(count);
```

the page still crashes. I haven't a clue why it cannot handle this code. Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem..? The page opens fine in firefox and IE9.

--update--

To describe crash more vividly: chrome begins loading the page. While the page is still completely blank, things start to slow down, and my entire machine becomes more and more unresponsive, until I can only move the mouse and nothing happens on mouseovers or clicks. The computer remains at a standstill for about 10 minutes, loads the "Aw, snap!" error page, and remains slow and unresponsive for another 5 minutes following the crash.
Here is the entire function that causes the error.

```
            var polys = [];
            var labelsAr = [];
            var poly; 
            var point; var point2;
            var marker;
            var label;
            var map;
            if (document.getElementById("map") != undefined) {
                // init map
                map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map")); }

            var pnames;
            pnames = "<%=pnames%>";
            var labels = pnames.split(",");


 function setupmap(){
     if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
         if (document.getElementById("map") != undefined) {


       polyfip = [];
       <%=polyfipSt%>

       // add map controls and set loc
       // the map = new GMap2 statement is not within a code block
       map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
       map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
       map.setCenter(new GLatLng(32.80, - 83.50), 7); 
       var colour = "#ff6666";

       var tooltip = document.createElement("div");
       map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_PANE).appendChild(tooltip);
       tooltip.style.visibility="hidden";

       <%=output%>

       //PROBLEM CODE
               for (var i=0; i<polys.length; i++) {
                    GEvent.addListener(polys[i], "click", function() {
                        var evtObj = window.event ? event : e;
                        for (var i=0; i<polys.length; i++) {
                            if ( this == polys[i] ) {
                                if (evtObj.ctrlKey) {
                                    map.closeInfoWindow();
                                    clickCounty(labels[i]); //a function elsewhere defined with simple if-else checks to highlight the county
                                }
                                else {
                                    if ( document.forms["pageform"].MainContent_CountySelection.options[i].selected==true && countiesSelected==1 ) {
                                        clickCounty(labels[i]);
                                        map.closeInfoWindow();
                                        }
                                    else {
                                        var overlaylatlng = this.getVertex(0);
                                        for (var j = 0; j < document.forms["pageform"].MainContent_CountySelection.length; j++) {
                                            document.forms["pageform"].MainContent_CountySelection.options[j].selected=false;
                                            var tempPoly = polys[j];
                                       tempPoly.color = "EFEDB0";
                                            map.addOverlay(tempPoly);
                                            }
                                        countiesSelected = 0;
                                    //an infowindow with some js function links
                                    var infoWindow = map.openInfoWindowHtml(overlaylatlng,"<form id='f" + i + "' name='f" + i + "'  method='post' action='countystats.aspx'><input type='hidden' name='countyName' id='countyName' value='" + labels[i] + "' /></form> County:  "+labels[i]+" <br /><br /><a href='javascript:submitForm(\"f" + i + "\")'>Core Data</a><br /><form id='fs" + i + "' name='fs" + i + "'  method='post' action='countystats2.aspx'><input type='hidden' name='countyName' id='countyName' value='" + labels[i] + "' /></form><a href='javascript:submitForm(\"fs" + i + "\")'>Single Tract Statistics</a> <form id='fsc" + i + "' name='fsc" + i + "'  method='post' action='getACScounty.aspx'><input type='hidden' name='countyName' id='countyName' value='" + labels[i] + "' /></form><a href='javascript:submitForm(\"fsc" + i + "\")'>ACS All Tracts in County Statistics</a> <br /><a href=getsp1.aspx?countylist='" + polyfip[i] + "'>Census2010 County</a> <form id='fscsp" + i + "' name='fscsp" + i + "'  method='post' action='getACScountysp.aspx'><input type='hidden' name='countyName' id='countyName' value='" + polyfip[i] + "' /></form><a href='javascript:submitForm(\"fscsp" + i + "\")'>Census2010 Sub-County</a>");
                                        clickCounty(labels[i]);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
          //END PROBLEM CODE
        }
    } 
}
```

<%=output> is a whole slew of polygons written from vb code into the polys[] array, and they appear on the map fine.

If I comment out the PROBLEM CODE segment of the script the page loads fine without the functionality needed. If I include the segment, the page crashes. However, if I omit the PROBLEM CODE segment, and include a different for loop ANYWHERE within this function, the page crashes. Even a for loop such as

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) { }
```

will crash the page. I have been stuck with this problem for days now, and it is driving me crazy. Anyone have any ideas as to what the problem may be..?

Also, if I go to the console in chrome and type in a sample loop, it executes normally. i.e. if I type

```
for (var i=0; i<polys.length; i++) {
    GEvent.addListener(polys[i], "click", function() {
         alert("Listening!");
    });
}
```

the map generates listeners on each overlay that fire correctly when clicked, as desired. Again, including something like this within the function crashes the page, but in the console it works fine.

Comment: When you copy/paste that simple loop into your console on a blank page, does it crash it? ... If not, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Define "crash". Describe an exact behaviour.

Comment: If by "crash" you mean "I got an 'Aw, snap.' page.", then please visit `chrome://crashes` and submit a bug/crash report. If you can reproduce the problem, we'd love to see code.

Answer (score 1):

don't use `int` to declare the counter... javascript is dynamically typed.

use `var`

```
var count=0;
for ( var i=0; i<5; i++)
    count=1;
alert(count);
```

Comment: +1 Still strange that it would crash his browser...mine just throws an unexpected identifier error.  I was nervous about trying it though :).

Comment: My mistake, I wrote the question wrong. I do use var to declare i. It still crashes with the "Aw, snap!" error page.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post what was calling the loop, as well as take a few [heap snapshots](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/heap-profiling.html)?
Get one directly before the loop and, if possible, a few while the loop is running before it crashes.

The loop itself is harmless, but the code calling it could be causing an endless scoping issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I tried tons of stuff and I finally found something that works, but makes no sense. Comment please if you understand this.

I defined a separate function called addListeners() with the EXACT code in the problem area as the body, omitted the problem code from the setupmap() function, called the addListeners() function from the same line that the problem code was removed from, and globalized the variable polyfip[]. So, there is no change in code except for the problem code is within it's own block.

Anyone know why this resolves the issue? Beats the hell out of me..

Answer (score 0):

What is your `polys.length`? If it's big/huge, you are just running out of your JavaScript V8 VM heap (taking a heap snapshot is really a good advice.) In this case you will see the "Aw, snap!" error. What you describe as a "solution" in your answer tentatively reduces the memory footprint of your code.

Comment: polys.length is a value of 159. Even an insertion of an empty loop in the setupmap() function causes the error. An empty loop of 5 iterations can't possibly cause a memory exhaustion. Do you think so..?

Comment: Well, the memory issue seems very unlikely to me, but heap profiling will nevertheless be useful, at least to have some insight of the program behavior. Take one snapshot before the loop, the other one while the loop is running (as advised by @user1090190). Then you can compare them (a built-in function) to learn about memory allocations between them.